# Project Reactor Schedulers elastic using old threadlocal value

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using spring webflux to call one service from another via Schedulers.elastic()

```
Mono<Integer> anaNotificationCountObservable = wrapWithRetryForFlux(wrapWithTimeoutForFlux(
                notificationServiceMediatorFlux.getANANotificationCountForUser(userId).subscribeOn(reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers.elastic())
        )).onErrorReturn(0);
```

In main thread i am setting one InhertitableThreadLocal variable and in the child thread I am trying to access it and it is working fine.

This is my class for storing threadlocal

```
@Component
public class RequestCorrelation {

    public static final String CORRELATION_ID = "correlation-id";

    private InheritableThreadLocal<String> id = new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    public String getId() { 
       return id.get(); 
    }

    public void setId(final String correlationId) { 
       id.set(correlationId); 
    }

    public void removeCorrelationId() {
       id.remove();
    }
}
```

Now the issue is first time its working fine meaning the value i am setting in threadlocal is passed to other services.

But second time also, it is using old id(generated  in last request).

I tried using Schedulers.newSingle() instead of elastic(), then its working fine.
So think since elastic() is re-using threads, thats why it is not able to clear / or it is re-using.

How should i resolve issue.
I am setting thread local in my filter and clearing the same in myfiler

```
requestCorrelation.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
chain.doFilter(req,res)
requestCorrelation.removeCorrelationId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never tie resources or information to a particular thread when leveraging a reactor pipeline. Reactor is itself scheduling agnostic; developers using your library can choose to schedule work on another scheduler - if you decide to force a scheduling model you might lose performance benefits.

Instead you can store data inside the [reactor context](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context). This is a map-like structure that’s tied to the subscriber and independent of the scheduling arrangement.

This is how projects like spring security and micrometer store information that usually belongs in a threadlocal.

Comment: can you elaborate the difference b/w elastic() vs newElastic(), as I have solved this using newElastic

Comment: using `newElastic()` eg. in a `@Controller` method will create a new pool of threads for each endpoint invocation, so for each request. But then your app is back to one thread per request model, which voids one of the main benefits of the reactive model

Comment: +1 to what Simon said. Creating a thread pool for each request might blow up your application quite quickly with OOM errors. You didn’t solve the issue but rather creates a new, bigger one.